# C++ another unique_ptr incomplete type question

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, forward-declaration, incomplete-type

Have looked at various similar questions here but still can't figure out why the following code does not compile:

```
// these three are defined somewhere
class A;
std::unique_ptr<A> make_a(); 
void take_a(std::unique_ptr<A>&&);

int main(){
   take_a(make_a()); // this fails
   return 0;
}
```

According to [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr):

> If the default deleter is used, T must be complete at the point in
> code where the deleter is invoked, which happens in the *destructor,
> move assignment operator, and reset member function* of
> std::unique_ptr.

As far as I understand, none of these (*destructor, move assignment operator, nor reset member function*) happens in `main`.

So why does compiler needs the definition of `A` here?

Comment: It's possible that `take_a` doesn't actually take ownership of the object, thus `main` would need to delete. Since `main` has a `unique_ptr` within its scope, realistically it would need to know how to delete the object it holds.

Comment: They have to be defined somewhere https://godbolt.org/z/o45K6xq3x

Comment: Forward declare `class UPA;` that is declared elsewhere as `struct UPA { std::unique_ptr<A> ptr; };` and then use that as the opaque type.  All problems can be solved with an extra level of indirection, except for the problem of too many levels of indirection.

Comment: *"As far as I understand, none of these (destructor, move assignment operator, nor reset member function) happens in main"* - That temporary you created *is in* main. Whatever happens inside `take_a`, that temporary still needs to be destroyed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since main has a unique_ptr within its scope, realistically it would need to know how to delete the object it holds.

It's possible that take_a doesn't actually take ownership of the object, thus main would need to delete.

Comment: Thank you! Now it definitely makes sense! Is it correct that the calls `take_a(make_a())` is equivalent to the `auto a = make_a(); take_a(std::move(a));`?

Comment: @frumle Not exactly; since its a temporary object, as opposed to an actual variable, but similar to `{ auto a = make_a(); take_a( std::move( a ) ); }` (noting the extra brackets to add scope)

Comment: Yes, I got it, thanks! Yet it looks like a bad practice to me: to make possible for function `take_a(A&&)` taking rvalue reference not to take ownership of the object, isn't it? It means that I can use the original instance `a` after I have "moved" it and passed to `take_a`, this looks very error prone, why is it even allowed?

Comment: @frumle, that is a good question. A compiler will typically warn when you're using an object after a `move`, but there's nothing that says someone has to take ownership.

Answer (score 1):

`main` gets a temporary `unique_ptr` from `make_a()`, let's call it `X`. It then passes an rvalue reference to `X` to `take_a`. It still has the destroy `X`. Hence, it has to call the destructor after `take_a`, even though `X` would typically be empty at that point.

Comment: Thank you! You are right. This fact that "X would typically be empty at that point" made me thing that the destructor of `A` should not be called in the scope of `main`, because it has been `moved` and the pointer should be empty after the `take_a()` call. Now I see that the crucial word in your answer is `typically`, as @ChrisMM clearly explained. The possibility for `X` to remain valid after `take_a(std::move(X))` call is what makes the compiler to ask for the definition of `A`. I missed this point.

Answer (score 0):

We need class A description (at least constructor and destructor) in order to create and move `std::unique_ptr<A>` objects; `take_a(make_a())` is creating such object because `make_a()` is pass-by-value. It first creates a new `unique_ptr<A>` object, initialize it (using default constructor), and then update its value and returns this new object. Here the default constructor/destructor is being used, which the compiler is unable to find.

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

class A {
    public: A() {}
    public: ~A() {}
};

std::unique_ptr<A> make_a() {
    std::cout << "make";
    std::unique_ptr <A> tt = nullptr;
    return tt;
} 

void take_a(std::unique_ptr<A>&&) {
    std::cout << "take";
}

int main(){
   take_a(make_a()); // this works now
   return 0;
}
```

**Edit:** Forgot to add the [link](https://godbolt.org/z/7Ehx3cWcc). Works the other [way](https://godbolt.org/z/7G7aoccv8) too.

Comment: Works other way too https://godbolt.org/z/7G7aoccv8

Comment: Yes, as expected, thank you.

Comment: @Jishan Shaikh Thank you. I mentioned, that both `make_a()` and `take_a(A&&)` are defined in other unit (say `def.cpp`) and they of course know the definition of `A`. What I did not understand is why the calls in other unit  (`main.cpp`) require the definition of `A` and the forward declaration is not enough. My reasoning was that both the constructor and destructor of A are called in `def.cpp`, while in `main.cpp` the only destructor of the *empty* `unique_ptr` must be called. Empty, because the `take_a` will take the ownership of the pointer. See @ChrisMM answer.